# Where can I find MIDAS library source code?

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I investigate a strange bug in my Delphi application and suspect that the problem might be in Midas.dll. I need the source code to review. Is it open? Where can I find it?

I have XE7 and Delphi 10 Seattle installed and I see only interface units loading midas.dll, but not the source of Midas itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a complete set of prior Delphi versions installed, but the source files are in the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0\source\data\dsnap\midas
```

folder for XE4, but I can't see any sign of them in XE6 (but I don't have C++ installed, so can't tell whether the source would be in that or it's not longer distributed).  If you have XE7 and Seattle, you should be able to download e.g. XE4 from your Registered Downloads (?) page on Edn.Embarcadero.Com.  It's obviously not the current version but might let you find what you're looking for.

Comment: I see it in RAD Studio\9.0\source\data\dsnap\midas, and the same for RAD Studio\11.0, 16.0, and 17.0, according to a quick search with Windows Explorer. I have the Pro SKU installed for all of them.

Comment: @KenWhite:  Interesting.  I wonder if it's because I didn't include C++ in my XE8 and Seattle installs - I started not installing it after I noticed how much Boost baggage there was in a previous version.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I didn't install Builder with XE8 (at least it's not on my Start Menu for that version), but I have the Midas source in the 16.0 tree.

Comment: @KenWhite:  Oh.  Mine's the Enterprise SKU btw.  Oddly, my XE4 dsnap folder doesn't have a midas sub-folder nor any of the .CPP etc files it contains in XE4, it just has the datasnap source files like datasnap.DBClient.Pas etc.

Comment: I have that folder (and the source) in XE4/8/Seattle, and not in XE3/5/6/7. Strange. ??

Comment: @MartynA, don't you know how about Tokyo? I would like investigate [what's happening here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49681070/8041231). The error gets lost in MIDAS, but I'd like to see where and why. Thank you! (already upvoted in February :)

Comment: @Victoria:  Well, I have Seattle and Tokyo installed (Delphi, not CPP), but neither of them have the Midas folder mentioned in my answer, and the only instances on my h/disk of the files it contains (e.g. Alchemy.Cpp) are in that folder.

Comment: @MartynA, thank you! So maybe it's a black box now :(

Answer (score 0):

The source code was first made available in Delphi 2010.

It is located under the Delphi installation directory in the `source\db\midas` sub-directory. In later releases it can be found in `data\dsnap\midas`.

The source for MIDAS is not always installed but I don't know which component specifically needs to be included to install it.

Comment: I guess this could depend on whether you've installed C++Builder.

Comment: @TOndrej I don't think so. It's installed by the Delphi installer.