# FireDAC truncated error message in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

FireDAC is returning a truncated message in `TClientDataset.OnReconcileError`. The message is

> [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_NAME". The conflict occurred in database "DATABASENAME", table "dbo.TABLENAME", column ''CD

The error comes from `Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.ReconcileCallback`, parameter pErrMessage. Call stack of the error:

```
ucdClientDataSet.TcdClientDataSet.cdInternalReconcile($11E17C90,$E8A8A70,ukInsert,raAbort)
Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.ReconcileCallback(0,???,2,547,$11DE2990,$12038D90,$11F97F60,nil,$11F98B90,0,???)
MidasLib.DllGetDataSnapClassObject((202032032, 0, 0, (36, 191, 2, 18, 0, 134, 133, 14)),???,(no value))
:006f9a7b DllGetDataSnapClassObject + $1E32A
MidasLib.DllGetDataSnapClassObject((202032032, 0, 0, (36, 191, 2, 18, 0, 134, 133, 14)),???,(no value))
:006f9366 DllGetDataSnapClassObject + $1DC15
MidasLib.DllGetDataSnapClassObject((37671188, 1, 0, (0, 44, 2, 11, 25, 0, 0, 0)),(37671188, 1, 0, (192, 236, 145, 14, 100, 0, 0, 0)),(no value))
:006fa085 DllGetDataSnapClassObject + $1E934
Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.Reconcile(???)
Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates(0)
ucdClientDataSet.TcdClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates(0)
```

The message error code is 547. If I execute

```
select * from sysmessages where error = 547 and msglangid = 1033
```

in SQL Server, the message is:

> The %ls statement conflicted with the %ls constraint "%.*ls". The
>   conflict occurred in database "%.*ls", table "%.*ls"%ls%.*ls%ls.

**Edit**

To simulate the problem, here is it:

Create two tables in SQL Server (i'm using 12.0.2000.8), one referencing the other

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE_A(FIELD_PRIMARYKEY INT NOT NULL) 

ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE_A ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FIELD_PRIMARYKEY_1 PRIMARY KEY (FIELD_PRIMARYKEY)

CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE_B(FIELD_FOREIGNKEY INT)

ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE_B ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FIELD_FOREIGNKEY FOREIGN KEY (FIELD_FOREIGNKEY) REFERENCES TEST_TABLE_A(FIELD_PRIMARYKEY)
```

In Delphi (10.1 update 2), create a project and add:

TFDConnection: configure the connection in the database where the test table was created;

TFDQuery: connect with the FDConnection, and put the SQL text: "select * from TEST_TABLE_B";

TDatasetProvider: connect the Dataset property to the FDQuery;

TClientDataset: connect the ProviderName property to the Provider;

TButton: put the code:

```
  ClientDataSet1.open;
  ClientDataSet1.insert;
  ClientDataSet1.fieldbyname('FIELD_FOREIGNKEY').asinteger := -1;
  ClientDataSet1.post;
  ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(0);
```

In ClientDataset.OnReconcileError, add the code:

```
  try
    E.RaiseOuterException(Exception.Create('Error'+#13+#13+E.Message));
  finally
    Action := raAbort;
  end;
```

Error message:

> Error
>
> [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_FIELD_FOREIGNKEY". The conflict occurred in database
>   "DBBALSAS_TESTE_PE", table "dbo.TEST_TABLE_A", column 'FIEL.

I did the same insert, but insert a FDQuery directly, and the error was complete:

```
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE_B(FIELD_FOREIGNKEY) VALUES(-1)';
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

> [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_FIELD_FOREIGNKEY". The conflict occurred in database
>   "DBBALSAS_TESTE_PE", table "dbo.TEST_TABLE_A", column
>   'FIELD_PRIMARYKEY'.

Comment: And, what do you expect anyone here to be able to do about it? If it is getting truncated, then FireDAC is probably not providing all of the data to the format string, or not in a way that the format string is expecting. Either way, you should [report it to Embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: What is the question? *"FireDAC truncated error message in SQL Server?"* ?

Comment: I dont expect that anyone should do anything about it. I do expect that, maybe, that's something solveble, like some configuration of max length of FireDAC error, or even of SQL Server. Something. Dont worry, I dont excpect that you MUST do anything for me. This is a forum, with people (including you) with a lot of experience, and maybe someone more experient in FireDAC or SQL Server can help in any way. Thanks for the comment

Comment: @SertacAkyuz the question is why is getting truncated.

Comment: I don't believe this is a FireDAC problem. If you can reduce the problem to a minimal verifiable example using only FireDAC, post it here with all necessary version information and I'll dig into that.

Comment: @Victoria I'll do that. Thank you

Comment: @Victoria I editted the question. When building the exemple, I noted that the error only happen when using clientdataset. If I use only FireDAC, the message is complete. So maybe thats a midas problem

Comment: Thank you! I'm able to reproduce. The problem is with MIDAS. Let me check this deeper.